# Adding MaterialUI or FluentUI breaks routing in Microsoft Teams app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, microsoft-teams

I am building a tab app inside Microsoft Teams and would like to leverage MaterialUI as my component library.  As soon as I install MaterialUI, the routing that was created by Teams Toolkit when I created my app breaks.

This is my App.tsx, which was generated by Teams Toolkit.  All I did was delete the routes I didn't need.

```
import React from "react";
// https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/quick-start
import { Provider, teamsTheme } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Tab from "./Tab";
import "./App.css";
import { useTeams } from "@microsoft/teamsfx-react";

/**
 * The main app which handles the initialization and routing
 * of the app.
 */
export default function App() {
  const { theme } = useTeams({})[0];
  return (
    <Provider theme={theme || teamsTheme} styles={{ backgroundColor: "#eeeeee" }}>
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/tab" />
        </Route>
        <>
          <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
        </>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I get this error:

'Router' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'BrowserRouter' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("XXX/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)

I get the same error for Router, Redirect, and Route.  I tried changing BrowserRouter to MemoryRouter and HashRouter, with the same error.  I have run npm update and installed @types/react-router-dom.  I tried npm install react@18.2.0, the version listed in the package.json of react-router-dom, and also npm install react@18.0.0, the version listed for MUI.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/teamsfx-cli": "1.*"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the [fluent ui northstar](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.65.0) library that does not work with React 18: `import @fluentui/react-northstar`.

Either use React 17 (and the previous version of the react router), or remove the fluent ui northstar dependency (you probably don't want it, first because you are using material, so you already have UI library and don't need yet another one, and second it's deprecated and superseded with Fluent UI components).

To remove, try something as simple as:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/tab" />
        </Route>
        <>
          <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
        </>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

The fluent ui themes won't be supported, but you likely don't need them anyway because you are saying you will be using Material (that is incompatible with fluent ui themes)